# Prove that if $x^3 - x > 0$, then $x > -1$

Tags: proof-verification

I know this probably seems like an easy problem, but I generally struggle with inequalities, so I was looking to see if someone could verify that the following proof of mine is correct. This was an even problem in my book, so no answers are provided. Please note that the variable $x$ is in the set of all real numbers.

**Proof by contrapositive**

Note: $x^3 - x > 0 \iff x(x+1)(x-1) > 0$

1) $x \leq -1$

2) $x + 1 \leq 0$

3) $x - 1 \leq -2$

4) $x(x+1) \geq 0$

5) $x(x+1)(x-1) \leq 0$

6) Therefore, if $x^3 - x > 0$, then $x > -1$

Comment: Seems ok, but why not simply prove $x^3 \leq x$? Seems much easier.

Comment: Wow, that sure simplifies things :D Thank you!

Comment: Nice. Also, <----> can be expressed as dollarsign /iff dollarsign

Comment: Do not make a series of assertions with no explanation of how they are related. If you did that in everyday speech  nobody would understand you. Write (i) $x\leq  -1\implies x+1\leq 0.$...(ii). By (i), $x\leq -1\implies x(x+1)\geq 0$...(iii). $x\leq -1\implies x-1\leq -2\implies x-1\leq 0$....(iv). By (ii) and (iii), $x\leq -1\implies x^3-x=[x(x+1)][x-1] \leq 0.$... The extra brackets in (iv) are for clarity: (ii) says something about $x(x+1)$ and (iii) says something about $x-1,$  so  in (iv) we separate them by extra brackets for easier reading.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @KSplitX Gotcha, thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but it can be streamlined.

If $x\le -1$, then $x^2\ge-x$, so $x^3\le-x^2$. But $-x^2\le x$ and therefore
$$
x^3\le x
$$
that is, $x^3-x\le0$.

Comment: $x^3-x$ has 3 real zeros and hence 2 turns.  How can the OP's answer be correct?

Comment: @sharding4 The question says “If $x^3-x>0$ then $x>-1$”, not “$x^3-x>0$ if and only if $x>-1$”. And the statement to prove is true.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the general inequality laws $a\le b\implies {1\over a}\ge{1\over b}$ when $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, $a\ge b\implies ac\ge bc$ if $c\ge0$, and $x^2\ge0$ for all $x$, we have

$$x\le-1\implies{1\over x}\ge-1\ge x\implies x={x^2\over x}\ge x\cdot x^2=x^3\implies x^3-x\le0$$